# Elo Chess Algo: Assigning K-factor to separate players in one event loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, chess

Below is a portion of the Elo chess rating algo (pardon the naming convention, it is provisional):

```
 let newRankRed = red[rank] + (redK * (results[result] - winProbRed))
 let newRankBlue = blue[rank] + (blueK * (Math.abs(results[result]-1) - winProbBlue))
```

The K factor (redK, blueK) is a number that will change depending on how many matches a Player has had. Player objects are stored in a DB and the record property (number of matches they had) is simply a number property on the Player object. My question is this: Two players had a match and the result was submitted to the app. The app goes into the DB, fetches both Players and checks their record to determine the right K factor for each Player. Two players, two separate K factors: What is the best way to assign the right K factor? I know we can have a  bunch of conditional statements like:

```
if (red.record >= 0 && red.record <=10) redK = 32
else if ...
```

But this would produce long and clumsy code and it would have to be done for each Player.

Can someone please suggest a better alternative?

Comment: there's no "best" K factor, It's a parameter that you have to choose based on your expectations. If you're looking for advise what a good K factor would be you may be better asking it on chess stack exchange.

Comment: There are only 3 possible K-Factors: 32, 24, 16. It will be based on how many matches a player had. Two players,  each one has his own K-factor. Just need to know how to assign both K factors without having to write a long series of conditional statements.

Comment: If you only want 3 K-factors it won't be a long series of conditional statements.

Comment: Please make your comments useful and relevant to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out. Below is a portion of the solution; red and blue are player objects with a 'record' property:

```
let redK, blueK

let red = await PlayerData.getPlayerById(redId)
let blue = await PlayerData.getPlayerById(blueId)

[[red, redK], [blue, blueK]].forEach((pair) =>{
  if(pair[0].record >=0 && pair[0].record <= 12) pair[1]= 32
  else if(pair[0].record >=13 && pair[0].record <= 24) pair[1]= 24
  else pair[1]= 16
})
```

This saves me from having to re-write the conditional statements for each Player. If anyone has a better solution, would be great to see it.

Comment: like, make a function?